# Should I ignore the HTTP status code in the Box API's responses?

Tags: box-api

I've recently noticed that when I attempt to upload a file with a name that already exists, Box returns me an error with a HTTP status code of 201 (Created), but the error JSON's "status" member is 409 (Conflict).

Should I be ignoring the actual HTTP status code, and instead treating the JSON's value as the authoritative status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, you should ignore the HTTP status code. We allow uploads of multiple files in a single request, each of which can have different outcomes. Say I upload 3 files in a single request:

Upload 1 => bad name
Upload 2 => success
Upload 3 => bad file

201 doesn't make sense here, but neither does 400. Until we've found a better solution, you should parse each file object returned to see what the result of the upload was.